# Web3 sending TX times out after 280 seconds because network lag

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js

When I submit a transaction via web3 and metamask, it will await 280 seconds before timing out and returning the transaction receipt.

How can I catch this error and handle with it so that my app can continue waiting for the transaction to be mined?

Is there a way to loop it with the tx hash that you can generate prior to it timing out?

EDIT: What is the best way to handle this, by using filter? By simply catching and running a filter for the 50+ blocks it can run max, doesn't seem like the best way. Also, will the Txhash remain the same if I generate it before I execute the transaction and the transaction is delayed for a day due to gas costs?

Answer (score 0):

I've been searching solution to 50 Blocks problem for long enough and I've found one.

What you can do is:

*1. Wait for **transaction hash** once you've sent the transaction.* Use this [LINK](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth.html#sendtransaction) for reference.

*2. Once you've received one, call **web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt** to get the transaction status using transaction hash.* Now refer this [LINK-2](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth.html#gettransactionreceipt)

**NOTE : It (getTransactionReceipt) will return NULL until the transaction is mined!**

Hope it helps!

Comment: How do you await JUST the transaction hash?

Comment: Like this: `await web3.eth.sendTransaction({
    from: '0xde0B295669a9FD93d5F28D9Ec85E40f4cb697BAe',
    to: '0x11f4d0A3c12e86B4b5F39B213F7E19D048276DAe',
    value: '1000000000000000'
})
.on('transactionHash', function(hash){
    console.log("Hash : " + hash);
})`