# Error: Cannot find module 'truffle-hdwallet-provider'

Tags: truffle, nodejs, hardware-wallets

I got the following errors while trying to deploy my smart contract:

```
sers-Air:lottery user$ node deploy.js

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:582

    throw err;

    ^



Error: Cannot find module 'truffle-hdwallet-provider'

    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:580:15)

    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:506:25)

    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:17)

    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)

    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/user/Documents/prod/EthereumCasts/lottery/deploy.js:1:88)

    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:688:30)

    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:699:10)

    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:32)

    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:537:12)

    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:529:3)

users-Air:lottery user$



I also tried to change it to const result = await new web3.eth.Contract(JSON.parse(interface))

.deploy({ data: '0x' + bytecode })

.send({ from: accounts[0] });
```

as suggested in the other thread but it didn't work. My github repository:

https://github.com/damianjnc/lottery

I did `npm install --save truffle-hdwallet-provider@0.0.3` but now got that error:

users-Air: lottery user$ node deploy.js

Attempting to deploy from account `0x14Ca642FA083121605fc860dB0024254D3FaCd61`

```
(node:31456) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Transaction was not mined within 50 blocks, please make sure your transaction was properly send. Be aware that it might still be mined!

at /Users/user/Documents/prod/EthereumCasts/lottery/node_modules/web3-core-method/src/index.js:375:45

at tryCatcher (/Users/user/Documents/prod/EthereumCasts/lottery/node_modules/web3-core-promievent/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)

at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/Users/user/Documents/prod/EthereumCasts/lottery/node_modules/web3-core-promievent/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:497:31)

at Promise._settlePromise (/Users/user/Documents/prod/EthereumCasts/lottery/node_modules/web3-core-promievent/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:555:18)

at Promise._settlePromise0 (/Users/user/Documents/prod/EthereumCasts/lottery/node_modules/web3-core-promievent/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:600:10)

at Promise._settlePromises (/Users/user/Documents/prod/EthereumCasts/lottery/node_modules/web3-core-promievent/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:679:18)

at Async._drainQueue (/Users/user/Documents/prod/EthereumCasts/lottery/node_modules/web3-core-promievent/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:125:16)

at Async._drainQueues (/Users/user/Documents/prod/EthereumCasts/lottery/node_modules/web3-core-promievent/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:135:10)

at Immediate.Async.drainQueues (/Users/user/Documents/prod/EthereumCasts/lottery/node_modules/web3-core-promievent/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:16:14)

at runCallback (timers.js:705:18)

at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:676:5)

at processImmediate (timers.js:658:5)

(node:31456) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)

(node:31456) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

users-Air:lottery user$

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try installing `@truffle/hdwallet-provider` like this in the console (same location from where you're deploying):

```
npm install @truffle/hdwallet-provider
```

Good Luck!

***Edit 2020-06-17:** As of 2019-08-22, the package `truffle-hdwallet-provider@1.0.17` has been deprecated and renamed to `@truffle/hdwallet-provider`. ([Source of reference](https://www.npmjs.com/package/truffle-hdwallet-provider)).*

Comment: It helped but now I got that errors: node:31456) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Transaction was not mined within 50 blocks, please make sure your transaction was properly send. Be aware that it might still be mined!(node:31456) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:31456) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated.

Comment: This is when you're txn is not mined within 50 blocks on Ethereum Blockchain. You can refer to my answer here: [https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/62349/web3-sending-tx-times-out-after-280-seconds-because-network-lag/62401#62401]. I've found an alternative solution for this problem. Give it a try!

Answer (score 3):

UPDATE:

truffle-hd-wallet provider has been depreacted:
 https://www.npmjs.com/package/truffle-hdwallet-provider

Instead use @truffle/hdwallet-provider:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@truffle/hdwallet-provider

After this @truffle/hdwallet-provider will be successfully installed - then reference in required file as follows:

```
var HDWalletProvider = require("@truffle/hdwallet-provider");
```

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem. What worked was replacing the "truffle-hdwallet-provider" in the require method argument at here: `const HDWalletProvider = require('truffle-hdwallet-provider');`

with `@truffle/hdwallet-provider`

`const HDWalletProvider = require('@truffle/hdwallet-provider');`

and `truffle compile` finally worked.

But make sure you install it first: run this first:

$ npm install @truffle/hdwallet-provider

Answer (score 1):

use this as dependancies.

```
  "dependencies": {
    "solidity-coverage": "^0.5.4",
    "solium": "^1.1.7",
    "truffle": "^4.1.13",
    "web3": "^1.0.0-beta.35",
    "coveralls": "^3.0.2",
    "ethereumjs-wallet": "0.6.2",
    "truffle-hdwallet-provider": "0.0.6",
    "ganache-cli": "^6.1.8"
  }
```